# having difficulty with xml writing

Tags: android, xml

I was trying to make a xml file using xmlSerializer. Which will take 2 values from ui, username & password. So, each entry will be appended to the xml file. 
If i use the below code, than it only keeps the last entry-

```
FileOutputStream fileos= getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(xmlFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Again, if i use MODE_APPEND instead of private than it takes all the xml tags given -like version and so on.

```
FileOutputStream fileos= getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(xmlFile, Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

But i need to append the entries only- which is username and password tag in the xml file.

Below is my total code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

EditText txtKey;
EditText txtValue;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtKey = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtvwKey);
    txtValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtvwValue);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}




public void saveClk(View v) 
throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException
{
    final String xmlFile="userMemo.xml";
    String key= txtKey.getText().toString();
    String val= txtValue.getText().toString();

    try {
    FileOutputStream fileos= getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(xmlFile, Context.MODE_APPEND);

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();              
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
    xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8",true);
    xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "userData");
        xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "userName");
            xmlSerializer.text(key);
        xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"userName");
        xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"password");
            xmlSerializer.text(val);
        xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "password");             
    xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "userData");
    xmlSerializer.endDocument();
    xmlSerializer.flush();
    String dataWrite=writer.toString();
    fileos.write(dataWrite.getBytes());
    fileos.close();
    } 


    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

How am i going to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You're using xerces-j right?
Unless it's a very big (say some hundreds of Mo) xml file, I suggest you use DOM instead of SAX, more readable.

It would look like:

```
public void saveClk(View v) throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException {
    final String xmlFile="userMemo.xml";
    // the name I suppose
    String key= txtKey.getText().toString();
    // the password I suppose
    String val= txtValue.getText().toString();

    // Load the xml from the file
    DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
    parser.parse(xmlFile);
    Document doc = parser.getDocument();

    // Create a userData node: <userData></userData>
    Node userDataNode = dom.createElement("userData");

    // Create a username node: <userName></userName>
    Node userNameNode = dom.createElement("userName");
    // Add the userName node a  value as a child text node
    // -> <userName>username</userName>
    Text nodeVal = dom.createTextNode(key);
    userNameNode.appendChild(nodeVal);

    // Create a password node: <password></password>
    Node passwordNode = dom.createElement("password");
    // Add the userName node a  value as a child text node
    // -> <password>password</password>
    nodeVal = dom.createTextNode(value);
    passwordNode.appendChild(nodeVal);

    // -> <userData><userName>username</userName><password>password</password></userData>
    userDataNode.appendChild(userNameNode);
    userDataNode.appendChild(passwordNode);

    // Get the document's root XML node
    NodeList root = doc.getChildNodes();
    // append the newly created node as a new child (so keeping the existing data)
    root.appendChild(userDataNode);

    // Write updated XML
    doc = parser.getDocument();
    OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc);
    format.setIndenting(true);
    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(new FileOutputStream(new File("userMemo.xml")), format);
    serializer.serialize(doc);
}
```

The problem in your attempt is that the MODE_APPEND is related to the file writer, not to the xml serializer.